# SQL - How to get total sum based on two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables, one is companies orders (`order id`, `customer name`, `sum`) and other is debts (`order id`) which includes orders that haven't been paid. I need to get customers with biggest `total debt`. Some customers have made more than 1 order. What is the best solution to do this? Thank you very much!

Orders table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders( order_id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30), sum INT );    
    INSERT INTO orders VALUES
    (1, 'Jack Smith', 123),
    (2, 'Mary Jane', 61),
    (3, 'John McCane', 90),
    (4, 'Jack Smith', 512),
    (5, 'Mary Jane', 33);
```

Debts table:

```
CREATE TABLE debts( order_id INT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO debts VALUES 
(1),(4),(5);
```

Right now I have something like this:

```
SELECT name,SUM(sum) FROM orders INNER JOIN debts ON orders.order_id = debts.order_id GROUP BY name;
+------------+----------+
| name       | SUM(sum) |
+------------+----------+
| Jack Smith |      635 |
| Mary Jane  |       33 |
+------------+----------+
```

Desired result would look like this:

```
name               sum
Jack Smith         635
Mary Jane          94
John McCane        90
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It's an easy one to solve, but you need to show us you're trying to learn before we answer it!

Comment: What would the desired result look like. Edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Added my current code and what the result would look like

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,sum from orders o inner join debts d on o.order_id = d.order_id order by o.sum  desc
```

Will give you all customers with debt ordered in descending order. Add `limit 1` if you want the customer with highest debt

```
select name,sum from orders o inner join debts d on o.order_id = d.order_id order by o.sum  desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(sum) FROM `orders` WHERE id IN (select order_id FROM debt)

This might help you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
SELECT name,SUM(sum) FROM orders INNER JOIN debts ON orders.order_id = debts.order_id GROUP BY name;
```

Thank you everyone for answers.